# Compilation error while creating array as key of unordered map

Tags: c++, arrays, unordered-map

I am compiling the below program with `g++ -std=c++11 lol.cpp` and getting a weird error. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>

int main(void)
{
  std::unordered_map <std::array<int, 2>, int> abc;
}
```

These are the errors: https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/f1f007bc8d3756ff2c92

Comment: What are weird errors?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/f1f007bc8d3756ff2c92

Comment: `unordered_map` doesn't know how to hash a `std::array`.

Comment: @101010 Are you sure? Because [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848868/using-unordered-map-on-array-of-doubles) answer here says it does.

Comment: @Lokesh Please put error messages verbatim in your question, not in a link.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's 130 lines long and I have no idea which portion is the relevant one. That's why I have pasted the gist link.

Comment: @Lokesh How are you sure that answer was correct?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't know for sure.

Comment: @101010 Hmm... That's sad to know. Anyway, I want use two integer values as the hash key. Isn't there any easy way other than define a struct and how to hash it?